# readline() not outputting correct line

Tags: python, readline

I want to make a settings file so my python script can remember settings after a reboot. I used the command `f.readline()` but the output is different giving the amount of lines I read.

example:
the text document is

```
1
2
3
```

and when I use this script to print out the information.

```
f = open("test.txt", "r")

print(f.readline(1))
print("-") #i used this to see if the output is blank since it will leave a empty space    
print(f.readline(2))
print("-")
pirnt(f.readline(3))
print("-")
```

the output is:

```
-
1
-


-
2

-
```

can someone explain what i am doing wrong or how i can improve it?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Have you checked the docs to see what that number (2 in f.readline(2) for example) represents?

Comment: the `f.readline()` without passing a number **keeps** reading the file from where it stopped previously. What this means is that you can omit all numbers and you will get what you want. And you probably forgot an empty line on the top of the output.

Comment: Thanks for the solving the problem but how can I for instance read a specific line if I don't know from wich line he starts reading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter of `readline` isn't the number of line you wish to read but the number of bytes you wish.

To access the file **by line number** you can use `readlines()`:

```
f = open("test.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
print(lines[0])
print("-") #i used this to see if the output is blank since it will leave a empty space    
print(lines[1])
print("-")
pirnt(lines[2])
print("-")
```

Be aware that `readlines()` fetch all the file at once and not line by line. Sometimes that's not what you realy want to do.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of `readline` takes an optional *size* argument which you have specified, which however you do not need if you intend to read the file line by line:

```
f.readline(1)
#          ^ read 1 byte
```

The parameter is not synonymous to *line number* as you assume.

Since you really intend to read *line by line*, you should not specify this size parameter:

```
f.readline() # reads one line at a time
```

An empty line will return `'\n'` and at the end of the file, you'll have `''`.